# Puppet over WAN to implement configuration changes to linux clients

Tags: linux, puppet, wide-area-network

As the title suggests, I need to find a way to implement a system that can  change configuration to over 800 linux clients, for a client.

The problem stems from the fact that we are not allowed to use the cloud or know what changes will be made to the system, we are being told the changes will happen frequently and over time and they need the infrastructure in place to make it happen. Not to mention the whole operation will span 15+ countries for a total of 50 offices.

I have checked everywhere for a similar case but came up empty.

I don't even know if this is viable, however if anyone has dealt with something similar or know of a way to do this I would be very grateful.

Thank you;

P.S: Puppet is also client's demand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet, chief, ansible etc. could always be wrapped by VPN. Every host you need to control you have to provision with vpn client which connects to your server and then you can manage all your client hosts from one central place.

Comment: Would site-to-site work or individual connections between each host a must? Also would we need more than 1 master-slave of puppet or several slaves for each office?

Comment: Using openvpn you can configure even client-to-client to work. You can isolate clients from each other if  additional security required, so clients will see just VPN-server. You will need just individual connection from client to VPN-server, client establishing VPN connection will allow you to travers almost any clients' Firewall/NAT. Then you configure puppet or any orchestrator of your choice to connect over vpn network. Then you can use any protocol for orchestration, even non-encrypted, as vpn will encrypt everything itself over WAN.